# AccessDeniedException: 403 does not have storage.objects.list access to config-management-release

Tags: google-anthos

I have google cloud console trial account with anthos enabled. When configuring anthos config management, i am getting accessdeniedexception.

Command Ran : gsutil cp gs://config-management-release/released/latest/config-management-operator.yaml config-management-operator.yaml

Exception : AccessDeniedException: 403 account-dv@fabric-275411.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.list access to config-management-release.

Service account has required privileges. But still throwing the exception. How to solve this issue? Tried with by creating service account with different names.

Below are the roles associated with serviceaccount:

```
roles/composer.environmentAndStorageObjectAdmin
roles/compute.admin
roles/compute.loadBalancerAdmin
roles/compute.networkAdmin
roles/compute.securityAdmin
roles/container.admin
roles/container.clusterAdmin
roles/container.clusterViewer
roles/editor
roles/gkehub.admin
roles/gkehub.connect
roles/gkehub.viewer
roles/iam.securityAdmin
roles/iam.serviceAccountAdmin
roles/iam.serviceAccountKeyAdmin
roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator
roles/iam.serviceAccountUser
roles/logging.admin
roles/logging.configWriter
roles/logging.viewer
roles/monitoring.admin
roles/owner
roles/redis.admin
roles/resourcemanager.projectIamAdmin
roles/servicenetworking.networksAdmin
roles/stackdriver.accounts.editor
roles/storage.admin
roles/storage.objectAdmin
roles/storage.objectViewer
roles/viewer
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to [1.3.0](https://cloud.google.com/anthos-config-management/docs/release-notes#March_24_2020) or later versions should resolve this.

Let me know if you still need any further assistance